# SQLite is telling me a column does not exist

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing an app that can store an insurance card, where the user enters their information and it is stored in a database.  The app launches with a list of previous incidents, and this is where the problem occurs.  It is telling me that column "driverone" does not exist.

I'm fairly new to programming, and very new to SQLite, so any and all advice will be greatly appreciated.  I know this topic has come up before here, and I searched the responses and still can't figure out what's going on.

Here is the code where I define my database:

```
public class DbSchema {
    public static final class CrashTable {
        public static final String NAME = "crash";

        public static final class Cols {
            public static final String UUID = "uuid";
            //TODO: "column 'driverone' does not exist...fix it
            public static final String DRIVER_ONE = "driverone";
            public static final String INSCO = "insco";
            public static final String POLICY = "policy";
            public static final String PHONE = "phone";
            public static final String EMAIL = "email";

            //public static final String DRIVER_TWO = "driver_two";
            //public static final String INSURANCECOMPANY_TWO = "insurancecompany_two";
            //public static final String POLICYNUMBER_TWO = "policynumber_two";
            //public static final String TELEPHONENUMBER_TWO = "telephonenumber_two";
            //public static final String EMAILADDRESS_TWO = "emailaddress_two";

            //public static final String DATE = "date";

        }
    }
}
```

And here's where I create my database:

```
private static final String CRASH_TABLE_CREATE_STATEMENT = "create table " + CrashTable.NAME + "(" +
        " _id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        CrashTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
        //CrashTable.Cols.ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        CrashTable.Cols.DRIVER_ONE + ", " +
        CrashTable.Cols.INSCO + ", " +
        CrashTable.Cols.POLICY + ", " +
        CrashTable.Cols.PHONE + ", " +
        CrashTable.Cols.EMAIL + ", " +
        ");";
```

And this is where the error occurs:

```
public class CrashCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper{
    public CrashCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public Crash getCrash() {
        String uuidString = getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow(CrashTable.Cols.UUID));
        String driverone = getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow(CrashTable.Cols.DRIVER_ONE));  <------ Error here
        String insco = getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow(CrashTable.Cols.INSCO));
        String policy = getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow(CrashTable.Cols.POLICY));
        String phone = getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow(CrashTable.Cols.PHONE));
        String email = getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow(CrashTable.Cols.EMAIL));

        //String theirName = getString(getColumnIndex(CrashTable.Cols.DRIVER_TWO));
        //String theirInsCo = getString(getColumnIndex(CrashTable.Cols.INSURANCECOMPANY_TWO));
        //String theirPolicy = getString(getColumnIndex(CrashTable.Cols.POLICYNUMBER_TWO));
        //String theirTelephone = getString(getColumnIndex(CrashTable.Cols.TELEPHONENUMBER_TWO));
        //String theirEmail = getString(getColumnIndex(CrashTable.Cols.EMAILADDRESS_TWO));
        //long date = getLong(getColumnIndex(CrashTable.Cols.DATE));

        Crash crash = new Crash(UUID.fromString(uuidString));
        crash.setYourName(driverone);
        crash.setInsCo(insco);
        crash.setPolicy(policy);
        crash.setTelephone(phone);
        crash.setEmail(email);

        //crash.setTheirName(theirName);
        //crash.setInsCo_Two(theirInsCo);
        //crash.setPolicy_Two(theirPolicy);
        //crash.setTelephone_Two(theirTelephone);
        //crash.setEmail_Two(theirEmail);

       // crash.setDate(new Date(date));

        return crash;
    }
}
```

Here's my log, for reference:

```
06-22 10:59:49.645 31983-31983/com.bignerdranch.android.crashcourse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.bignerdranch.android.crashcourse, PID: 31983
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.crashcourse/com.bignerdranch.android.crashcourse.CrashListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'driverone' does not exist
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'driverone' does not exist
      at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
      at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:87)
      at com.bignerdranch.android.crashcourse.database.CrashCursorWrapper.getCrash(CrashCursorWrapper.java:21)
      at com.bignerdranch.android.crashcourse.CrashShop.getCrashes(CrashShop.java:53)
      at com.bignerdranch.android.crashcourse.CrashListFragment.updateUI(CrashListFragment.java:110)
      at com.bignerdranch.android.crashcourse.CrashListFragment.onCreateView(CrashListFragment.java:46)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1988)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:754)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1653)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:364)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: It seems that you have added a column and you are working with an older version of your table because your `CREATE` statements throws an error (remove the trailing comma `CrashTable.Cols.EMAIL + ", " +`)

Answer (score 0):

When you create your table, you should not put a comma after the last attribute, which is EMAIL in your case.

Also, AUTOINCREMENT is useless in SQLite, because it is already included in the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: I tried that, and still nothing.  But it did need to be fixed, so thanks!

Comment: `AUTOINCREMENT` makes a difference, but usually it could and should be avoided.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: If you log your query, what is the result ?

Comment: How do I log the query?

Comment: I finally figured it out. I had made changes to my table prior to posting this question and I didn't update the VERSION.  Live and learn, right?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) documents the differences.